# What does the second "as" used in this sentence mean?

Tags: sentence-meaning, sentence-structure

> Darwin had a phrase to describe those ignorant of evolution: they look at an organic being as a savage looks at a ship, as at something wholly beyond his comprehension.

In "**as** at something wholly beyond his comprehension", *as* is followed by *at*. So this clause has, in my view, omitted "a savage looks". In other words, the full expression of this clause should be "as a savage looks at something wholly beyond his comprehension".

Is the second *as* used as a complement to describe how incomprehensive the ship is to a savage or just trying to tell readers another object, which is something wholly beyond savage's comprehension, that the savage looks at?

Comment: This is the **comparative** use of "as", where it is being used to compare the way they look at an organic being with the way that a savage looks at a ship, i.e as something beyond their comprehension.

Comment: The second ***as*** means exactly the same as the first one - *they look at an organic being **as a savage** looks at a ship, **as [a savage looks]** at something wholly beyond his comprehension*, where stylistically it doesn't really make any difference whether the actual word ***as*** is explicitly repeated in this "parallel construction" context. But native speakers wouldn't normally repeat the *entire* construction as added [in brackets] in my "teaching" version here.

Comment: Perhaps OP is being confused by the possible alternative reading *...as **they** (those ignorant of evolution) **look** at something wholly beyond **their** comprehension*. That reading can't be ruled out until you reach the singular pronoun ***his***, since the "deleted" elements *could* have been plural ***they + look***, which makes this text a little bit of a "garden path" construction.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Thank you for being patient, and you mean that both "as" convey the same meaning. So can I rephrase this sentence into "as a savage looks at a ship and/or something wholly beyond his comprehension"? In relation to "as", is there any difference right now?

Comment: If you say to someone "I think of you as a friend", it doesn't mean the same as "I think of you _and_  a friend". Darwin imagined the 'savage', who had never seen any boat larger than a canoe, being baffled at the sight of a large ship.

Comment: Syntactically speaking, *...as a savage looks at a ship and/or something wholly beyond his comprehension* is just a "contracted" form of the full parallel construction *...as a savage looks at a ship and/or **as a savage looks at** something wholly beyond his comprehension*. It's a stylistic choice to "delete" all 5 of those highlighted words - it would still be syntactically fine (and mean *exactly* the same) if we repeated just the preposition *(**at**)*, OR we could repeat ***as at***, OR (unlikely, but still "valid") ***as a savage at*** - but NOT ***as looks at*** with no subject.

Comment: The point I was making is that *in your specific example*, you have to pay special attention to note exactly which elements form part of the parallel construction, because there are effectively *two **nested / overlapping** comparisons being made*. But even if you "mis-parse" it, and interpret the text as saying that "those ignorant of evolution" look at an organic being ***as if it was something wholly beyond their** comprehension*, that wouldn't make any difference to the overall *meaning* of the assertion being made. It's really just a quirk of how the syntax works in this context.

Answer (score 0):

You misinterpret the quotation.

Darwin meant that *people ignorant of evolution* look at an organic being in the same way that a 'savage' (a person from a primitive culture) looks at a modern ship. In *both* cases, the thing being looked at is beyond the comprehension of the person looking.

Comment: So, do you mean that the subject of the second as is both the people ignorant of evolution and the savage?

Comment: The subject is definitely the savage, as the pronoun in "beyond his comprehension" is his.

Comment: OK - _they look at an organic being [in the same way that] a savage looks at a ship; [he looks at it] as something beyond his comprehension_. But the meaning is clearly that the people look at the organic being in the same way. The pronoun could just as well have been omitted.

Comment: See my second comment under the question itself. Unless I'm having a "senior moment", that pronoun *(**his** = a savage)* could in principle have been ***their** = those who are ignorant of evolution*, so you can't really say it makes no difference whether it's present or omitted. Syntactically, I mean. Semantically, taken as a whole, it makes no difference whether the final clause attaches to the savage or the ignorant.